# Replace or remove words, characters, numbers, and extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I writing a JavaScript code that would replace(remove) some words, characters, numbers and extension of file names. So far I could only remove the extension of the file names using the following code:

```
fileName = fileName.replace(/(?:\.[^.]*$|$)/, '');
```

I have file names like the following:

```
2.5_TR125_10x10.jpg
AB1_TR3201_50x50.png
```

I would like to keep TR part only and remove

```
2.5_ and _10x10.jpg
AB1_ and _50x50.png
```

I have tried to include these words in between () in the code above but it didn't work.

Any idea how to include these word in the list to be removed

Comment: `s.match(/_(TR\d+)/)[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to keep `TR` part, so the `TR` substring after an underscore until next underscore.

You can `String#match()` to extract it:

```js
const strs = ['2.5_TR125_10x10.jpg','AB1_TR3201_50x50.png'];
const regex = /_(TR[^_]*)/;
for (const s of strs) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.match(regex)?.[1]);
}
```

Here, `_(TR[^_]*)` matches `_` and then captures into Group 1 a `TR` substring and then any zero or more chars other than an underscore.

If you plan to remove parts of a string with separate regexps, it will be less efficient. Say, you want to build on your current regex to use with `String#replace` (note the `$` alternative should be removed, it makes no sense to replace end of string position, an empty string, with an empty string, and your `(?:\.[^.]*$|$)` pattern is in fact `\.[^.]*$`), then you'd use

```js
const remove_patterns = [String.raw`^[^_]*_`, String.raw`_\d+x\d+`, String.raw`\.[^.]*$`];
const regex = new RegExp(remove_patterns.join('|'), 'g');
const strs = ['2.5_TR125_10x10.jpg','AB1_TR3201_50x50.png'];
for (const s of strs) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.replace(regex, ''));
}
```

Here, all occurrences of the following pattern matches will be removed:

- `^[^_]*_` - start of string, zero or more chars other than `_` and a `_`
- `_\d+x\d+` - `_`, one or more digits, `x`, one or more digits
- `\.[^.]*$` - a dot, zero or more chars other than a dot and end of string.